# How to find pdf files with 2 strings in pdfgrep?

Tags: linux, pdf, grep

I use `pdfgrep` in Fedora 25 and I need to locate pdf files containing "just" two strings: I tried like this but I think it is wrong:

```
pdfgrep -HiRn 'string 1|string 2' .
```

How should this command be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks good. The problem is likely to be the pipe symbol `|`. Standard `grep` doesn't handle that without escaping it. Since the `man` page for `pdfgrep` says "pdfgrep works much like grep," it may suffer the same syntax limits.

To make it work you will need to escape the `|` like this `\|`.

```
pdfgrep -HiRn 'string 1\|string 2' .
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried as Chindraba recommend, but it didn't work with pdfgrep for me. This did the job for me:

```
pdfgrep -ril -e "search term 1" -e "search term 2" >matches.txt 2>badfiles.txt
```